# Connect to Microsoft SQL Server Database from Hosted Website

Tags: php, sql-server

I currently have a site that is hosted through a host site(Inmotion Hosting). I have created a few mySQL databases on it and use php to query it. I would like to do the same thing but connect/query my Microsoft SQL Database on my local network. Is there a way to do this? If so what is the best way to set it up?

I am currently using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (Will be upgrading soon)

Comment: `"on my local network"` - The application would need to be able to connect to the database.  Which means no firewall/router/etc. can be blocking it.  Note that opening database access to the internet isn't often the best idea, unless you really know your way around database security.

Comment: Good point @David. I am worried about the security issue. I would think there is a way to establish the connection with some levels of security though.